# How to access an array from another class in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a "struct" with information for a Login system.

```
struct AlmacenaUsuarios
{
    public string sUsuario;
    public string sUsuarioContra;
    public int iUsuarioTipo;
    public bool bUsuarioBloq;
}
```

I create an array in another class "cClassUsuarios.cs" to save user information in an array called .

```
public static void Usuarios()
{
 Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de usuarios");
 int iNusuarios = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

 AlmacenaUsuarios[] ArregloClase = new AlmacenaUsuarios[iNusuarios];

 for (int i = 0; i < iNusuarios; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAñada el nombre del usuario #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            ArregloClase[i].sUsuario = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la contraseña: ");
            ArregloClase[i].sUsuarioContra = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero del tipo de usuario: 1) Médico 2) Paciente:");
            ArregloClase[i].iUsuarioTipo = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            ArregloClase[i].bUsuarioBloq = false;    
        }
 }
```

I have another class "Program.cs" where I want to compare the input of the user with the information from the array "ArregloClase" in "cClassUsuarios.cs". I want to access the array values from "cClassUsuarios.cs" to compare them with the input of the user. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the declaration of the variable `public AlmacenaUsuarios[] ArregloClase` outside the `Usuarios()` method, but still within the Class. Then from Program.cs you want to keep a reference to cClassUsuarios.cs so you can access the ArregloClase array.